# Question on Infinitely Differentiable Functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be infinitely differentiable on $(-1,1)$ with $f(0)=1$ and has the following properties:

(1) $\vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert \le n!$ for every $x\in (-1, 1)$ and for every $n\in \mathbb N$

(2) $f'(\frac{1}{m+1})=0$ for every $m\in \mathbb N$

I need to:

Find the value of $f^{(n)}(0)$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$

Determine the value of $f(x)$ for every $x\in(-1,1)$

I claim that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and I wanted to prove this by induction. When $n=1$, we note that by (2), $f'(0)=0$ by the sequential criterion for limits with $m\rightarrow \infty$. However, I am not sure on how to prove the inductive step.

I note that from (1), we have $f(x)\le\frac{1}{1-x}$ by Taylor's Theorem.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) implies that $f''$ has a zero  in the interval $(\frac{1}{m+2}, \frac{1}{m+1})$
for each $m \in \Bbb N$, therefore $f''(0) = 0$.

The same argument can be repeated to show that each derivative $f^{(k)}$ has
a sequence of zeros converging to $0$.

(The estimate $\vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert \le n!$ is not needed for this
conclusion.)

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I realized that also by my approach the estimate of $n$-th derivative is not needed

Comment: @RobertZ: Thanks. – As it turns out, the question has been asked and answered before, unfortunately I did not notice that before posting the answer.

Comment: As far as I can see no answers there pointed out that the estimate on $f^{(n)}$ is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let us consider the case $n=2$ (try by your own the case $n>2$)

For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, by using the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of $f'$ at $0$, we have that there exists $t_m\in (-1,1)$ such that 
$$f'\left(\frac{1}{m+1}\right)=f'(0)+f''(0)\cdot \frac{1}{m+1}+\frac{f'''(t_m)}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}.$$
Since $f'\left(\frac{1}{m+1}\right)=0$ and we already know that $f'(0)=0$, it follows
$$f''(0)=-\frac{f'''(t_m)}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(m+1)}$$
which implies that as $m\to+\infty$,
$$|f''(0)|=\frac{|f'''(t_m)|}{2}\cdot \frac{1} {(m+1)}\leq\frac{M_3} {2(m+1)}\to 0.$$
where $M_3=\max_{x\in[-1/2,1/2]}| f^{(3)}(x)|$ (the assumption  $\vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert \le n!$ in $(-1,1)$ is not needed).